# How to get multiple GETs in one request?

Tags: rest, http, get

Is it possible to get multiple (let's say 300) calls with a single GET request? The protocol is HTTP/1.1 to a REST interface.

To be more explicit:

There is a REST-API and i have to call that through GET method. But the *problem* is that i have to make this request hundreds of times consecutively every day. So instead of many single requests (open connection, retrieve data, close connection) i would like get all hundreds of responses at once. Is it possible to concatenate many GET requests to retrieve all the responses at once?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean or what problem you're trying to solve.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: i have edited the question, i hope it's more explicit now.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your api to run over the given data 100 times and then send the response. Since you can request a get method only once
for e.g you can send an array of values and you can run the logic for each item in an array and get back an array containing all information at once

Comment: thank you for you answer.  the api is not mine and there is no possibility for me to modifiy it. it is just taking GET requests and responds accordingly.